# whenever I clicked on the capture Image button my app is crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity

Im trying to capture the image and send it to the next activity but whenever im clicking on the capture button my app crashes. here is the code below:

```
btn_capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //----function call
        captureImage();
    }
});

jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),ShowCaptureImage.class);
    i.putExtra("capture", bytes);
    startActivity(i);      //<--------- error is occuring here 
    return;
    }
};
return vw;
}
//------------PICTURE TAKEN FUNCTION--------------
private void captureImage() {
camera.takePicture(null,null, jpegCallback);
}
```

Comment: it would be easier if you add the error log

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: is this due to the size of byte array while sending in intent

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is happening when you try to get the Intent data in the `ShowCaptureImage` Activity. Can you post the code for that part?

Answer (score 0):

check on activityresult data and make sure that camera permission is added on manifest file